# Remove a value in a list with jq

Tags: json, jq

If I have a list like:

```json
{
  "animals": [
    "wolf",
    "bear",
    "cat",
    "lion",
    "snake",
    "tortise",
    "squirrel"
  ]
}
```

and I want to remove "bear" from the list. I found I can use:

```
jq 'del( .animals[1] )' animals.json
```

What if I want to remove a value by it's value name ie "bear"?

Comment: i.e. `.animals |= map(select(.!="bear"))`

Comment: Or simply `jq '.animals -= ["bear"]' animals.json`

Comment: ah yes, both of these were what I was looking for.